# Customizing Xamarin.Forms layouts

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm building an Android and iOS app using Xamarin Forms.

What I'm simply trying to do is set a background drawable on my Android app for my `ListView` items. The root view of my `ListView` items are `StackLayout`'s:

```
var listView = new ListView
{
    ItemsSource = items,
    ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
    {
        return new ViewCell
        {
            View = new StackLayout(...)
        };
    }
};
```

I know I can access the native element by using a custom renderer:

```
public class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement == null) {
            var nativeEditText = (EditText)Control;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure how this would work for a `StackLayout` (or any other layout for that matter).

I first extended `StackLayout`:

```
public class ListViewItem : StackLayout
{
}
```

And I read somewhere that layouts use the `VisualElementRenderer`, so I tried the following:

```
public class ListViewItemRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<StackLayout>
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<StackLayout> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        // any way to access the native element?
    }
}
```

But `VisualElementRenderer` does not seem to give me access to the native element.

So is there any way I can access the native elements of Layout elements? Or maybe there is a different way to simply set a background drawable on layouts within my Android app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though I still don't know how to access the native element of a layout, the `VisualElementRenderer` has a method for setting the background drawable on Android (which was exactly what I needed). So I ended up with the following:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<StackLayout> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    SetBackgroundDrawable(Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.listViewItem));
}
```

Comment: The VisualElementRenderer has a property called `Element` which returns the native element.

Comment: how to achieve the same in iOS ??

Comment: Hi I know this is an old post. But could please provide to me the entire android source code you ended up using. including the listview datatemplate and the stacklayout renderer. PLEASE!

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to hook into an existing **Layout renderer** and extending it to access the native element with extra capabilities like *background image*.

Eventually the support for *background-image* will be supported just like *background-colour* is, I imagine, across the **Layout** controls.  It may be worth while waiting for this as I can't see why they wouldn't implement these in a later release.

In the mean time you would need something that would work and is quite easy to implement?

Creating the background drawable via inheriting the renderer from a **Layout** may not be the simplest of solutions therefore, although does have its advantages as you can then re-use easily with the extra functionality across all **Layouts** for an application.

In your code for **ListViewItemRenderer**, however, it is inheriting from a **Xamarin.Forms** control (you specified **StackLayout**) and have not specified a native, platform dependent, control to be the base for the layout control that would have to match the Xamarin.Forms platform dependent control used.

Each **Renderer** is tied to a **native** element.  **Layout** controls will be no different than other custom native control renderers.

For a custom control, you will write a renderer something like the following (note I haven't specified a *layout* renderer as I haven't had a need to do this yet and am just going from past experience - but similar rules should apply to implementing a *renderer* for a *layout* as opposed to a custom control):-

```
// System.Windows.Controls.Grid in this case is the root native control for a WindowsPhone renderer of MyControl
public class MyControlRenderer : ViewRenderer<MyControlView, System.Windows.Controls.Grid>
```

There is a simpler approach, however to achieve what you want to do:-

The simpler approach would be instead of inheriting from the **Stack Layout** control, it would be better to inherit from **Grid** as the root of the control.

Then you can add an **Image** control to the **Grid** and also a **Stack Layout** for the same **Grid** *Row* and *Column*.

By doing the above you will be able to achieve a background-image across the entire listview item row.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Unless `VisualElementRenderer` is not the right renderer for layouts, I do think the renderers for layouts differ from custom control renderers. The `VisualElementRenderer` does not provide me a property (_Control_) to access the native control.

Comment: **Grid** and **StackLayout** derive from **Layout<View>**.  My hunch would be that you need to create a derivation from **ViewRenderer** as this is a shortcut to **ViewRenderer<View, RootNativeControlUsedForLayout>** and then apply the **Export** on this so that your custom class implementation gets called and executes.  You will then be able to within your own **ViewRenderer** implementation to add this extra support for a background image accessing the native root control appropriate for each platform.

Comment: My guess would be that the `StackLayout` would render as a `LinearLayout` on Android. So I tried `public class ListViewItemRenderer : ViewRenderer<StackLayout, LinearLayout>`, but `Control` stays null.

Comment: Would make sense, however they specify the base for *Android* as only **View** as they are also allowing the *renderer* to cover different **Layouts**.  I just saw that you managed a workaround, however if you do follow the advice above it **does** work and allow you to customize with gaining **root** access to the **native** element.